# How to pass a function and a list of its vector arguments?

Tags: r

I'm trying to write a function in R that will take as arguments, a second function and its arguments, some of which are vectors.  The ultimate result I want is to write a rolling function that calls a function to act on a time series, but I've tried all permutations of "apply" functions I can think of with no success, since "apply" functions all seem to apply a function to a vector element by element and what I want is to apply functions to vectors as a whole.  For example,

```
a = c(1,2,3); b = c(4,5,6)
sapply(a,function(x,y,c) c*t(x)%*%y,b,c=2)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    8   16   24
[2,]   10   20   30
[3,]   12   24   36
```

but what I really want is:

```
2*t(a)%*%b
     [,1]
[1,]   64
```

and be able to roll the function along a time series.  I've also tried writing
a generic function that contains a second function and its parameters as arguments, but I can't seem to get it to accept the parameters.  For example,

```
foo <- function(func,parm){
    return(func(parm))
}

foo(function(x,y,c) c*t(x)%*%y,parm=list(a,b,c=2))
Error in c * t(x) %*% y : 'c' is missing
```

The problem here is that func won't accept a list of arguments, but how does one
pass a list of arguments to a function?  Hope this isn't too confusing.  Thanks for any help offered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I have correctly guessed what you need, you need to do the following inside the function:

```
foo <- function(func,parm){
    return(do.call(func, parm))
}
```

This will call `func` with the arguments in `parm`. For example:

```
test = function(a,b) return(a+b)
> test(1,2)
[1] 3
> do.call(test, list(1,2))
[1] 3
```

Comment: If this answers your question, you can mark it as such by pressing the tick mark to the left of my answer. This signals that this question has been answered.