# passing arguements to a function within a function in r

Tags: r, function, parameter-passing

My problem is that I, want to make a function in R, which has one argument being some function (a probability density for example), and another argument which specifies the values the function should be evaluated in. Something like the following:

```
my_fun <- function(FUN, par){ FUN(par) } 

my_fun(FUN = dpois, par = c(x = 10, lambda = 2))
```

When I execute this in R I get the error:

> "argument "lambda" is missing, with no default".

My guess is that R does the following

```
dpois(x = par, lambda = "missing").
```

Any suggstions on how to get R to do:

```
dpois(x = par[1], lambda = par[2])
```

Comment: you're almost there `do.call(dpois, list(x = 10, lambda = 2))`, [related question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18802051/how-to-pass-a-function-and-a-list-of-its-vector-arguments)

Comment: Either `do.call` as rawr suggests or you could your function as `my_fun <- function(FUN, ...) FUN(...)` and use `my_fun(FUN = dpois, x = 10, lambda = 2)`

Comment: Tanks alot :). That was exactly what i wanted

Comment: you should prefer @alexis_laz's solution unless you need to pass different sets of parameters to different functions in which case you could use multiple lists of arguments